# Multi-theme for MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, themes

I am new to asp.net MVC and razor, but I'm trying to build a web app where more than one client can use the app (same URL and domain to access). The idea is to provide different theme for each client.
The theme name can be stored in user info after a user logs in or passed in query string when they land on my site.
Some of these clients want different layout for their header and footer, so I think CSS based solution will not suffice.
I'm using MVC 3.
Can anyone point me in the right direction to go about achieving this?
I'm thinking of creating a custom viewengine as some examples I have seen for webform. What is involved in doing this? Is there a better way?

Happy thanks giving for those celebrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate layout page for each client, then select the appropriate layout in `_ViewStart.cshtml`.

Comment: I gave this one the bounty as it's more like what I was looking for and more simple.

Answer (score 0):

[Controller.View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470743.aspx) has an overload that lets you specify a particular master layout from the action:

```
return View(string viewName, string masterName);
```

So if it's as simple as just using a different master page depending on the user, this isn't a bad approach.

Comment: Passing that all over the controllers would be a very bad idea.

Comment: Better to wrap up the logic in your own base controller.